# TypeError: can't convert into an exact number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, delayed-job

I'm queueing up a DelayedJob that runs a method that contains this scope:

```
scope :before, lambda {|time| {:conditions => ["created_at >= ? AND updated_at <= ?", Time.now.utc - 86400 * 14, Time.now.utc - time] }}
```

But when running the job, I get this error:

```
Class#update_all_numbers failed with TypeError: can't convert Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job into an exact number
```

The `time` variable in the scope would just be an integer (like `300`), but for some reason it's throwing the error. If I remove `- time` or just put in a static number there, it runs fine.

Comment: I have tried `time.to_i` but still get the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You could try replace raw arithmetic by

```
Date.today - 14.days
```

Comment: That part isn't the issue (see my last paragraph).